# XAMPP Configuration cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, xampp, fatal-error

Most Common Configuration Problem when you Work with google analytics - PHP Integration.

```
Fatal Error : Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttpException\RequestException' with message cURL error 60 SSL certificate Problem
```

This issue Come because of Lake of Configuration in XAMPP.

Does anyone have Solution for this. ?

Thanks,
Fareed.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html, the relevant part being _"Get a CA certificate that can verify the remote server and use the proper option to point out this CA cert for verification"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem by installing cURL Extensions:

In My Local System cURL Extensions was not Installed. and enable the extension php.ini file

I downloaded and installed the Extension and Restarted Apache. 
Working Perfectly Fine Now.